# Using testing-library findBy* on a component that uses setState causes a "not wrapped in act" warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I've got a React component which retrieves data using a Promise and then calls `setState` when the promise resolves. It then uses the updated state to change what's rendered.

When testing this, I use the [testing library](https://testing-library.com)'s [`findBy*` methods](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#findby) to wait for the rendered component to have been updated with the content from the Promise:

```
await findByText("Failure details", { exact: false });
```

My tests pass - they correctly wait until the component has re-rendered.  However, I get a warning like this when running them (I'm using Jest, but I don't think that's relevant):

```
Warning: An update to MyComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
```

[Everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56461528/wrapping-async-moxios-call-in-act-callback) [I've](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56410688/how-to-test-useeffect-with-async-function-and-setstate-inside) [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181009/jest-react-testing-library-warning-update-was-not-wrapped-in-act) [online](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2073) [that's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55047535/testing-react-components-that-fetches-data-using-hooks) [related](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15379) to this is either about components using `useEffect` or about tests which include explicit calls to `act` in them (mine don't), which I don't think should be necessary here - my test itself isn't changing the component, apart from the fact that it calls `render`.

In short, my situation seems simpler than those that others are writing about - I'm just using `setState` and the `findBy*` queries, nothing more complex.

Is there an equally simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, the solution was simple - upgrading React and React-DOM to >= 16.9.0. I didn't have to change my tests or my component.

16.9.0 includes [an asynchronous version of act](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/14853). As I say, I didn't have to explicitly use it, but it was obviously being used behind the scenes because it solved my problem.

Comment: After fixing this problem as described here, I did actually end up wrapping the component code which calls `setState` in a `useEffect` hook so that I could do [cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) and not try and set state on an unmounted component. But that didn't require me to do anything further about the act warning, the above was still sufficient.